# Reverse only string without digits within a for loop in a web scraper script

Tags: python, string, loops, web-scraping, reverse

This is the code i'm having problems with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get('https://www.whatever.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'lxml')
scraper = soup.find_all('article', {'class' : 'article fc '})

for q in scraper:
    result = q.find('div', {'class' : 'text-container'})
    print((result.text[::-1]))
```

The problem is the reversed 'result.text' output.
I want only the string part to be reversed and that it won't touch the integers.
How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a sample value for `result.text`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to reverse `result.text` as you explained:

```
' '.join([x if x.isdigit() else x[::-1] for x in result.text.split()][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' '.join(map(lambda word: word if word.isdigit() else word[::-1], "cat 1234 1cat".split()))
```